# 'onChange' event is getting called only once in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

I am using material-ui

Here my react component goes:

```
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = (theme) => ({
});

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {

  };

  state = {
    checked: true,
  }

  handleChange = name => event => {        
    event.persist()
    this.setState({ 
      [name]: event.target.checked 
    }, () => {
      if (event.target.checked) {
        this.props.parentMethod1(event.target.value)
      } else {
        this.props.parentMethod2(event.target.value)
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={this.state.checked}
              onChange={this.handleChange('checked')}
              value={user.id}
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={user.first_name}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default withStyles(styles)(SomeComponent);
```

**The problem is, I can select/unselect the checkBox only once**. 
After selecting/deselecting the checkbox, onChange event is not occuring.

Can you help me how to make Checkbox work as the way it is?
Thanks.

Here is the reproduced error:

https://codesandbox.io/s/y041zknrqv

Comment: Instead of using `event.target.checked` and `event.target.value` in the callback, you can put `checked` and `value` in variables the first thing you do in the function returned from `handleChange`: `const { checked, value } = event.target` and use that instead. This way you don't need to persists the event. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: This will remove the warning but issue is not fixed yet.

Comment: Hi there. I can't seem to reproduce the problem using similar code to yours: https://codesandbox.io/s/m788313rvp

Comment: Using just this much, we can't reproduce the error. The parent component has few synthetic events and it's too huge to add here. I will try to minimize the code and edit here.

Comment: @AndyJ   Please see the https://codesandbox.io/s/y041zknrqv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original codesandbox by OP: https://codesandbox.io/s/y041zknrqv

If the above codesandbox correctly demonstrates your actual problem, then your issue is that you mess up with `event.stopPropagation` and `event.preventDefault`

In both `Parent1` and `Parent2`, you provide `onClick` event handler to the div container and implement `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropagation` on both handlers. So here is what happens when you click the checkbox the first time:

- Checkbox receives click event and updates state, resulting in checked
  = true.
- Event bubbles up to `Parent2`. Here `onClick` triggers function `handleClick` of this component.
- in `handleClick`, `event.preventDefault` stops default action of browser for that event, meaning **future click events will not trigger checkbox**, while `event.stopPropagation` prevents parent components from firing `onClick`, meaning `Parent1` will **immediately never receive any click event.**

And now, from the second click event onwards, only `Parent2` can receive and response. Its children and its parents will not handle anything anymore. You can see the console log in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r75rp285xq

So, to fix your issue, remove `event.preventDefault` from `Parent2`'s `handleClick`. If you also want to correct behavior of `Parent1`, remove `event.preventDefault` from both components and remove `event.stopPropagation` from `Parent2`

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to change the value of checkbox. You must not pass same value `onChange` in your case

```
onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e)}
```

and your handle change function should be like

```
handleChange =event=> {        
    this.setState(prevState=>{ 
      checked: !prevState.checked
    }, () => {
      if (this.state.checked) {
        this.props.parentMethod1(this.state.checked)
      } else {
        this.props.parentMethod2(this.state.checked)
      }
    });
  };
```

This will change your value every `onChange` event.

Comment: I need values to my parent methods. Can you please go through this : https://codesandbox.io/s/y041zknrqv ? It might clear the question.

Comment: It is working fine when I just use in that component itself. Your parent components are not updating because you are not  pass the value to the parent component. please refer the link https://codesandbox.io/s/00qpz5vnxl

Answer (score -1):

Since you are passing the function a parameter, try converting it into an arrow function on your onChange event

```
<Checkbox
              checked={this.state.checked}
              onChange={() => this.handleChange('checked')}
              value={user.id}
              color="primary"
            />
```

Comment: No, not helping. Thanks

Comment: `this.handleChange('checked')` creates a handler function, `handleChange = name => event => {` rather than being the handler function itself. So while this is a good suggestion in general, it doesn't apply to this code.